# How to separate html pages and Python code in Web2py

Tags: python, web, web2py

I am working on a new Web project (with Web2py) and I need to define organisation where page design and code will be separate and made by different peoples. Web designers will use tools like Pinegrow then give files to coders. I need to define rules where Web designers may update there work without coders' intervention (and vice versa). My question : is it possible with Web2py and what are the restrictions and 'best rules' ?

Answer (score 1):

In web2py templates, all Python code goes in between the `{{...}}` template delimiters, so a simple rule would be "don't touch anything inside those delimiters." However, you will still run into two types of problems:

1. Designers won't be able to see an accurate representation of their work if simply loading the .html template in a browser (it must be served dynamically by web2py for the code to be executed).
2. Some types of structural changes made by the designers could break some of the code (in other words, some types of changes require simultaneously changing the design and the code).

Comment: Thx for this answer. I understand the 2/ point and it was clear for me. The 1/ point is more a problem, is'nt it any way to more separate, in differents files, html and code ? May be Web2py is not the best solution for it ?

Comment: In simple cases, you could simply have an `{{include ...}}` statement to dynamically include a template that contains code, or you could do some server-side or client-side parsing/DOM manipulation to dynamically alter a static HTML page. However, in the general case, it would be hard to avoid mixing markup with some kind of code. I don't think it's a web2py issue, as all frameworks (server and client side) ultimately involve some kind of mixing of markup and code. Can you point to a solution you have seen that allows you to keep all code completely separate (in non-trivial cases)?